# .htaccess leaves "index.php" in url after base rewrite,how to remove index.php and still have the rewrite working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with .htaccess url rewrites.I have the simple lines below and their function is to take each url after the base folder [where the .htaccess file is located]and insert index.php after wards,example if the url was example.com/basefolder/subdirectory1/subdirectory2 then it should be example.com/basefolder/index.php/subdirectory1/subdirectory2.

This happens perfectly,the problem is that on a local server the index.php part of the url is hidden but not on a remote server,I can still see in the url bar when on remote server.How do I hide it so that even though the url will still be example.com/basefolder/subdirectory1/subdirectory2 there will a hidden index.php hidden in the url?

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/basefolder/index.php/$1